# Having trouble with java class methods

Tags: java

ok so my assignment I'm supposed to write a class that stores a temperature that the user gives and checks it with the set parameters to see if Ethy/Oxygen/Water are either freezing or boiling and then display it at the end which ones will be freezing/boiling at the temperature that they entered. I have the majority of both the class and tester completed but I'm getting several errors on my code. I'm not asking anyone to give me the answer but if you could tell me what I'm doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it. Here is my code for class:

```
public class FreezingBoilingPoints {

    private int temperature;

    public FreezingBoilingPoints(int temp) {
        temperature = temp;
    }

    public void setTemperature(int temp) {
        temperature = temp;
    }

    public int getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    private Boolean isEthylFreezing(int temperature) {
        if (temperature <= -173) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private Boolean isEthylBoiling(int temperature) {
        if (temperature >= 172) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private Boolean isOxygenFreezing(int temperature) {
        if (temperature <= -362) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private Boolean isOxygenBoiling(int temperature) {
        if (temperature >= -306) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private Boolean isWaterFreezing(int temperature) {
        if (temperature <= 32) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private Boolean isWaterBoiling(int temperature) {
        if (temperature >= 212) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String showTempinfo() {
        if (isEthylFreezing()) {
            System.out.println("Ethyl will freeze");
        }

        if (isEthylBoiling()) {
            System.out.println("Etheyl will boil");
        }

        if (isOxygenFreezing()) {
            System.out.println("Oxygen will freeze");
        }

        if (isOxygenBoiling()) {
            System.out.println("Oxygen will Boil");
        }

        if (isWaterFreezing()) {
            System.out.println("Water will freeze");
        }

        if (isWaterBoiling()) {
            System.out.println("Water will boil");
        }
    }
}
```

and the code for my tester is below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FreezingBoilingTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int temperature;

        FreezingBoilingPoints temp1 = new FreezingBoilingPoints(0);

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a temperature: ");
        temperature = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println(showTempinfo());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) don't pass the temp inside methods, because you already have this value in member variable.

2) you can change if (condition) then true else false into return (condition) and it will be the same result, just for readability .

3) you should return boolean not Boolean wrapper until you need the wrapper.

```
public final class FreezingBoilingPoints {

    private int temperature;

    public FreezingBoilingPoints(int temp) {
        temperature = temp;
    }

    public void setTemperature(int temp) {
        temperature = temp;
    }

    public int getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    private boolean isEthylFreezing() {
        return (temperature <= -173);
    }

    private boolean isEthylBoiling() {
        return  (temperature >= 172);
    }

    private boolean isOxygenFreezing() {
        return (temperature <= -362);
    }

    private boolean isOxygenBoiling() {
        return (temperature >= -306);
    }

    private boolean isWaterFreezing() {
        return (temperature <= 32) ;
    }

    private boolean isWaterBoiling() {
        return (temperature >= 212);
    }

    public String showTempinfo() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        if (isEthylFreezing()) {
            result.append("Ethyl will freeze");
            result.append("\n");
        }

        if (isEthylBoiling()) {
            result.append("Etheyl will boil");
            result.append("\n");
        }

        if (isOxygenFreezing()) {
            result.append("Oxygen will freeze");
            result.append("\n");
        }

        if (isOxygenBoiling()) {
            result.append("Oxygen will Boil");
            result.append("\n");
        }

        if (isWaterFreezing()) {
            result.append("Water will freeze");
            result.append("\n");
        }

        if (isWaterBoiling()) {
            result.append("Water will boil");
            result.append("\n");
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FreezingBoilingTester
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a temperature: ");
    int temperature = scan.nextInt();

    FreezingBoilingPoints temp1 = new FreezingBoilingPoints(temperature );
    System.out.println(temp1.showTempinfo());
  }
}
```

**updated**:
you can use String concatenation:

```
String result = "";

if ( condition ) {
  result += "new result";
  result += "\n";
}
```

but this is not recommended in term of performance, because each += operation will create another String object in memory holding the new result.

Comment: ok yours actually helped me the most but I can't use the StringBuilder method in my program because we haven't learned it yet. How do I get it to return it without using the string builder?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your private methods are taking in a `temperature` and yet, you are not passing one in for your `showTempinfo()` method. Try removing the input parameters and using the `temp` set in the class. Also, you need to somehow set the `temp` before you call `showTempinfo()`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your `showTempinfo()`, you try to do `isEthylFreezing()`.

But it can't work ... isEthylFreezing is waiting for an int ... but it gets nothing ...

Comment: for public String showTempinfo() its says that "illegal start of expression" and that it requires a semi colon. Those are the only errors that I'm getting now

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the input that the user is giving you into the constructor for your FreezingBoilingPoints class. You're initializing that class with 0 and then asking for a temperature from the user. There's no relationship between the temperature the user provided and the class that you're using to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct your FreezingBoilingPoints object in your main method, then call showTempinfo() on it. Also, your private calc methods should use the member variable; there's no need to take it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the user input, `temperature`, into your `FreezingBoilingPoints` constructor. Also, the method `showTempInfo()` is instance specific. For example, you need to instantiate your object, `temp1`, by passing the user input with the constructor and then invoke `temp1.showTempInfo()`

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

1) All your "is..." methods are expecting for an int parameter, however when you're calling them, you're not passing anything. Remove the int parameter from either the method implementation or the method calls

2) You're missing a closing bracket for the method isWaterBoiling;

3) You marked the method "showTempinfo" as returning String, but you are not returning anything for that method. Either add the return command or remove the "String" from the method signature.